# Apache POI - reading modifies excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi

Whenever I open a excel file using the Apatche POI the file gets modified, even though I'm just reading the file and not making any modification.

Take for instance such test code.

```
public class ApachePoiTest {

    @Test
    public void readingShouldNotModifyFile() throws Exception {
        final File testFile = new File("C:/work/src/test/resources/Book2.xlsx");
        final byte[] originalChecksum = calculateChecksum(testFile);
        Assert.assertTrue("Calculating checksum modified file",
            MessageDigest.isEqual(originalChecksum, calculateChecksum(testFile)));
        try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(testFile)) {
            Assert.assertNotNull("Reading file with Apache POI", wb);
        }
        Assert.assertTrue("Reading file with Apache POI modified file",
            MessageDigest.isEqual(originalChecksum, calculateChecksum(testFile)));
    }

    @Test
    public void readingInputStreamShouldNotModifyFile() throws Exception {
        final File testFile = new File("C:/work/src/test/resources/Book2.xlsx");
        final byte[] originalChecksum = calculateChecksum(testFile);
        Assert.assertTrue("Calculating checksum modified file",
            MessageDigest.isEqual(originalChecksum, calculateChecksum(testFile)));
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(testFile); Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is)) {
            Assert.assertNotNull("Reading file with Apache POI", wb);
        }
        Assert.assertTrue("Reading file with Apache POI modified file",
            MessageDigest.isEqual(originalChecksum, calculateChecksum(testFile)));
    }

    private byte[] calculateChecksum(final File file) throws Exception {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.reset();
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
            int numBytes;
            while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                md.update(bytes, 0, numBytes);
            }
            return md.digest();
        }
    }
}
```

Test `readingShouldNotModifyFile` always fails, because the file gets always modified by Apache POI. More to it when testing on a blank excel file freshly created with MS Office, Apache POI cuts the file from 8.1 kb to 6.2 kb and corrupts the file.

Tested with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>
```

and also with version 3.12

Can I prevent Apache POI from modifying my files by other means then passing `InputStream` instead of `File`. I don't want to pass `InputStream` because I'm concerned about Apache's warning that it takes more memory and has some specific requirements to the `InputStream`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not passing in the readonly flag, so Apache POI is defaulting to opening the file read/write.

You need to use the [overloaded WorkbookFactory.create method which takes a readonly flag](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) + set that readonly flag to true

Change the line

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(testFile); Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is)) {
```

to

```
try (IWorkbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(testFile,null,true)) {
```

and your file will be opened read-only with no changes

Comment: I must have been blind cause somehow I missed that overloaded method. Thank you for pointing me to it :)