# Apache POI - How to offer excel file for download in a Grails application

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm having issues figuring out how to open an existing excel file, add data to it, output that file to a browser, and then close the workbook without saving any changes to it.

Previously I used this to create the Workbook:

```
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file))
```

And this to output it to a browser:

```
workbook.write(response.outputStream)
```

However I was running into memory issues, so I changed from FileInputStream to the WorkbookFactory:

```
workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file)
```

However this appears to modify the file (though it doesn't seem to actually edit anything). I tried using the overloaded function with readonly flag as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920260/apache-poi-reading-modifies-excel-file):

```
workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file,null,true)
```

However I cannot use `workbook.write()` anymore, as it complains that the file is readonly. Can anyone explain to me the proper procedure for doing this? Using workbookFactory solves my memory issues it seems, but I don't like that it's modifying the excel file somehow.

Comment: The problem is **how** using a `File` instead of a `FileInputStream` reduces memory footprints. Using a `File` opens the `*.xlsx` `ZipPackage` directly from the file. So not the whole `ZIP` content must be load in memory. But, of course, then the closing the `ZipPackage` will change the last-modified-parameter of the underlaying file although file's content will not be changed.

Comment: @AxelRichter I see. I suppose as long as the file doesn't change I'm fine with it, I was just nervous since I need that file's cell content to stay the same. I will look into Tuyens suggestions as well encase that ends up being worth it. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: I am not sure if you can be save that the file content will never change also in later `apachwe poi` versions. I suspect the mainly goal of using a file instead of an input stream is **not** reducing the memory footprint but having a file which is able storing the changings into itself after closing. This is only not fully implemented until now. My suspicion is because in binary formats (`*.xls*` `BIFF`) a random access file is opened while using a file instead of an input stream.

Answer (score 0):

With [`WorkbookFactory`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) you can only open an existing file and any process you do with it lead to modify it. Your problem is that you don't want to modify your file, so I propose for you a solution: make a copy of your original file => working on the copy (do any thing you want) => delete this copy after you done your job.

Comment: The problem is not `WorkbookFactory` but using a `File` instead of a `FileInputStream`. If `WorkbookFactory` uses an `FileInputStream`, then the problem dos not occur. But your suggestion is good.